# ionic cordova statusbar for ionic v1 not working

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

I have an ionic v1 app that I'm trying to resolve the status bar elements being faded out by my apps background.

I'm using the status bar cordova plugin.

I installed the cordova plugin for the status bar and see that it was installed in my config.xml.

I have the following config in my config.xml.

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~2.2.0" />
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />
```

The plugin was automatically added when I installed it. The preference is what I added. But this does not work. My statusbar background hasn't changed.

What am I missing here???

My versions:

```
global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0 

local packages:

    Cordova Platforms : android 6.3.0 ios 4.5.3
    Ionic Framework   : ionic1 1.3.2
```

Comment: what is your cordova and ionic version ?

Comment: Hi Manoj, added.

Comment: Does this help? https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/issue-with-cordova-plugin-statusbar-plugin-and-v1-project/122359/2

Comment: Hi Chris, already installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove the line from config.xml

```
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />
```

in app.js file in your ionic v1 app

add  the following code in your angular module run function

```
        if (window.StatusBar) {                    
                StatusBar.styleDefault();
                StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#262424');
            }
```